# Android, вложенный ListView

Tags: getview, android, listview

Здравствуйте! столкнулся с такой проблемой, что не совсем понимаю как правильно организовать структуру для вывода данных во вложенных ListView.

Есть задача - реализовать вот такой интерфейс:
[image]

Данный ко мне приходят с сервера в JSON'e, я их начинаю разбирать и вот тут я как раз уже застопарился. Если бы был одиночный список, без вложенности, я бы собрал массив строк (или объектов), отправил их в свой адаптер и после адаптер погрузил бы в ListView. Но как действовать тут - я не понимаю, в интернете тоже толком не нашел информации.
Заранее спасибо за ответы, подсказки, или за пинок в нужном направлении.

Comment: Если нужно 2 уровня, то ExpandableListView вам поможет.

Comment: @metalurgus всё равно вопрос остается:
1: он сворачивается по нажатию, но это я думаю можно будет отключать.
2: в Child надо грузить ещё один ListView.
Иерархия не упростилась и не изменилась

Comment: @ua6xh я как бы написал, "Если нужно 2 уровня"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите на [TreeView](https://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/).

Хотя этот интерфейс я бы сделал и на обычном ListView, и никакого вложенного ListView там не нужно.

Answer (score 2):

То, что вы показали, это не несколько `ListView`, а один, с кастомным адаптером, в котором для каждого item'а инфлэйтится тот или иной layout.