# ListView в ListView (вложенный листвью)

Tags: getview, android, listview, java

Я уже [спрашивал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/259804) ранее, как сделать вложенный листвью, ну в общем у меня получилось,
но результат пока не радует и появилась новая проблема: вложенный `ListView` превращается в скрол выводя только 1 итем списка, выглядит это вот так:

[image: listview]

Прокрутить я его не могу, тыкался в параметра, но как вытянуть его на все элементы и зафиксировать - я не нашел, параметр `android:minHeight` тоже не сработал. 
Товарищ @KoVadim написал:

> Хотя этот интерфейс я бы сделал и на обычном `ListView`, и никакого вложенного `ListView` там не нужно.

Но как это сделать без вложенного списка, я не знаю, видимо и надо делать без вложенного, но как?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: [Два списка на одном экране][1] - загляните сюда


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/259549/java-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5

Comment: > Я уже спрашивал ранее

И я вам ранее, в той же теме, на которую вы ссылаетесь, дал ответ, как это делается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

как сказал ранее [[@falstaf](/users/5517/falstaf)](/users/5517/falstaf)

> То, что вы показали, это не несколько ListView, а один, с кастомным адаптером, в котором для каждого item'а инфлэйтится тот или иной layout.

Реализуйте свой адаптер и в нем уже делайте все на что фантазии хватит
[хороший пример кастомизации listview](http://habrahabr.ru/post/133575/)

---

[[@ua6xh](/users/14126/ua6xh)](/users/14126/ua6xh)  у вас по сути listview с разными вьюшками, посмотрите в статье на которую я дал ссылку
  этот код создает вашу вьюшку

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
```

если вам заранее известны все возможные варианты просто создаете несколько вариантов лэйаутов и используете нужный, если нет можно генерировать view в коде.
Да, и обратите внимание на ViewHolder  он значительно увеличит производительность (можно создать несколько классов для разных вариантов).Если сильно упрощать то получается примерно следующие

```
 @Override

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup   parent) {
     LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View rowView = null;
 if(...){
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, parent, false);
     ...
  }
  else{
    rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout1, parent, false);
    .... 
    }

      return rowView;
 }
```

Comment: Так именно это я и [делаю][1]..., но не получается.

[1]: http://pastebin.com/QkurxRLk

Comment: Нет, вы не именно это делаете, вы делаете что-то весьме странное. Правильно ли я понимаю, что вы в методе `getView()` адаптера ищете какой-то ещё `ListView` и ему назначаете новый адаптер? Зачем это?

Comment: @falstaf - Да, всё правильно поняли, это я глупый, не думал что делаю всё как говорят. Разобрался с тем как "инфлэйтить", сейчас всё сделано на одном ListView, где подключаю нужные мне Layout.